# Material-UI Autocomplete, React Hook Form - Changing InputValue in Material UI Autocomplete with Use State in an OnChange?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I've been customising a Material UI Autocomplete within a Controller from React Hook Form, as part of a much larger form, with some difficulty.

The dropdown lists suggestions drawn from the database (props.items, represented here as objects) and if the suggestion is not there, there's the option to add a new one in a separate form with a button from the dropdown. This 'secondComponent' is opened with conditional rendering.

As it gets passed to the second form, the data is stored in state (heldData) and then passed back into the form via React Hook Form's reset, here as reset(heldData).

This updates the value of the form perfectly, as I have an onChange event that sets the value according to what was passed in. React Hook Form handles that logic with the reset and gives the full object to the onChange.

However, I also want to set the InputValue so that the TextField is populated.

In order to create a dynamic button when there are no options ('Add ....(input)... as a guest'), I store what is typed into state as 'texts'. I thought that I could then use the OnChange event to use the same state to update the inputValue, as below. However, when I setTexts from the onChange, the change isn't reflected in the inputValue.

Perhaps this is because the useState is async and so it doesn't update the state, before something else prevents it altogether. If so, it's much simpler than the other code that I have included, but wasn't certain. I have excluded most of the form (over 500 lines of code) but have tried to keep any parts that may be appropriate. I hope that I have not deleted anything that would be relevant, but can update if necessary.

Apologies. This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm quite new to React (and coding) and the code's probably a mess. Thank you

```
 **Form** 

import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import AutoCompleteSuggestion from "../general/form/AutoCompleteSuggestion";
import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const items = {
  id: 2,
  name: "Mr Anderson"
}
   
const items2 = {
  id: 4,
  name: "Mr Frog"
}

const defaultValues = {
  guest: 'null',
  contact: 'null',
}

const AddBooking = () => {

  const { handleSubmit, register, control, reset, getValues} = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultValues,
  });

  const [secondComponent, setSecondComponent] = useState(false);
  const [heldData, setHeldData] = useState(null)


  const openSecondComponent = (name) => {
    setSecondComponent(true)
    const data = getValues();
    setHeldData(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    !secondComponent.open? 
    reset(heldData):''
  }, [heldData]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  };

  return (
    <>

      {!secondComponent.open &&

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          <AutoCompleteSuggestion
            control={control}
            name="guest"
            selection="id"
            label="name" 
            items={items}
            openSecondComponent={openSecondComponent}
          />

          <AutoCompleteSuggestion
            control={control}
            name="contact"
            selection="id"
            label="name"
            items={items2}
            openSecondComponent={openSecondComponent}
          />

        </form>
     };

      {secondComponent.open?
        <SecondComponent/>: ''
      };
    </>
  );
};
```

And this is the customised AutoComplete:

```
**AutoComplete**

import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete,  from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import parse from "autosuggest-highlight/parse";
import match from "autosuggest-highlight/match";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";


const AutoCompleteSuggestion = (props) => {

  const [texts, setTexts] = useState('');
  
  return (
    
    <>
      <Controller
        name={props.name}
        control={props.control}
        render={({ onChange }) => (
          <Autocomplete
            options={props.items}
            inputValue={texts}  //NOT GETTING UPDATED BY STATE
            debug={true}
            getOptionLabel={(value) => value[props.label]}
            noOptionsText = {
              <Button onClick={()=> props.opensSecondComponent()}>
                Add {texts} as a {props.implementation}
              </Button>}
            onChange={(e, data) => {
              if (data==null){
                onChange(null)
              } else {
                onChange(data[props.selection]); //THIS ONCHANGE WORKS
                setTexts(data[props.label]) //THIS DOESN'T UPDATE STATE
              }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                onChange = { e=> setTexts(e.target.value)}
              /> 
            )}
            renderOption={(option, { inputValue }) => {
              const matches = match(option[props.label1, inputValue);
              const parts = parse(option[props.label], matches);

              return (
                <div>
                  {parts.map((part, index) => (
                    <span
                      key={index}
                      style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}
                    >
                      {part.text}
                    </span>
                  ))}
                </div>
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default AutoCompleteSuggestion;
```

Comment: You need to improve the formatting of your code and present it in digestible sizes. There's all kinds of syntax mistakes and redundant whitespace that make it extremely hard to follow right now.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, will do that. Think in cutting my code down and in posting on SO for the first time, I made it quite unreadable. Apologies